# REST API to create profile list Oracle responsys

Tags: oracle, rest, responsys

Could anyone let me know how can I create a profile list in Oracle responses via REST API call?
I could do it via UI but I need to do automation via javascript.

Comment: Typically the API is used for actions that would occur frequently, like many times per day.  What is your use case that you would need to create a new profile list so frequently via the API?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot create a profile list in Oracle Responsys via the API.  That functionality is only accessible via the UI.  You can update and merge on an existing list, but you cannot create a new one.